# Cannot exit X server, restart, shutdown or drop to tty when VGA monitor active

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, debian, xorg, linux-mint

I have a strange problem. If I connect an external VGA monitor to my laptop, exiting the X environment in any way crashes the computer.

For example, say I am working with my two monitors (the laptop's and one connected to my  VGA port) active. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F Key</kbd> should take me down to a tty. What actually happens is that the VGA screen goes blank, as you would expect, *but* the laptop screen, although still on, shows nothing. I know the screen is on because it is slightly more illuminated than when it is off.

When in this state, I can do nothing to regain access to the machine. I have tried:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F Key</kbd> (and even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F Key</kbd>, just in case) combinations and none seem to have any effect.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>  : Nothing
3. [Magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key): Nothing
4. Blindly typing my username and password and trying to reboot/shutdown or restart GDM or MDM: Nothing

The only thing that works is a hard reset.

The exact same behavior occurs when kiling the X server through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, rebooting or shutdown. There is no difference if I reboot/shutdown/log out using the WM's graphical menu or if I use the `shutdown` or `reboot`commands.

It is also not WM-dependent. I have the same problem using Cinnamon, Gnome 3, MATE and xfce4.

It is, however, VGA dependent. I have tried connecting another VGA monitor and have the same problem. I do *not*, however, have this problem if a screen is connected to the DisplayPort. It is, therefore, a VGA specific issue.

To make things even stranger, this only occurs when **both** screens are active. If *either* the laptop screen *or* the VGA monitor is inactive the problem goes away.

Finally, this problem arose when I installed the latest Linux Mint Debian (LMDE). It did not occur with the previous release of LMDE. I am not sure what has changed since I used the same kernel version in both releases (I had upgraded the kernel while on the previous release) and, I think, the same nvidia drivers. Oh, and yes, I *have* updated the nvidia driver.

Hardware:
[Dell M4500 laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-m4500/pd) 
CPU: Intel Core i7
RAM: 8GB 
Graphics: nVidia GT216 [Quadro FX 880M]

Software:
LMDE, kernel 3.2.0-2-amd64
Xorg: 1.11.4
nVidia kernel: 295.20-1+3.2.9-1

Possibly relevant files:
[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1209310/) 
[~/.xsession-errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1209308/)

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There are funny error messages in the logs. Have you tried a fresh installation?

Comment: @harrymc, this is a fresh install. I said I upgraded because i was using the previous release of LMDE before. I have corrected my question.

Comment: If you have an "OPTIMUS" option in the BIOS, try to activate/disactivate and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks I'll try that when I leave work. AFAIK, I do not have switchable graphics though so I doubt I will have such an option.

Comment: Is going back to the configuration where everything worked correctly is an option?

Comment: Not really, it would involve doing a fresh install all over again using an ISO from last year. I'd rather not. Plus, I am really curious about this, my guess is it is a bug in some VGA driver or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, LMDE Update Pack 5 came out yesterday. The problem was fixed when I updated my system. I don't know precisely which package was fixed but my current specs are:

LDME, kernel 3.2.0-3-amd64
Xorg: 1.12.1.902-1
nVidia kernel: 302.17+1+2+3.2.21-2

Oh well, all's well that ends well. On the assumption that it was the nvidia driver update that fixed it (though it may just as well have been xorg or the kernel upgrade) I am awarding the bounty to Stefan who needs it more than harrymc :).

Answer (score 1):

[This Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) has a more recent version of the nVidia closed-source driver. Alternatively, you can try nouveau, the open source nVidia X driver.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I can't use PPAs, I'm not on an Ubuntu-based system. I had a quick look at the PPA and the drivers you mentioned are Ubuntu-specific. The version I am using is straight from nvidia so my guess is that the version numbers are not comparable anyway. I'll check if there is a newer version of the driver. Using nouveau is not an option as I really really like my compiz.

Comment: Latest nVidia is 304, so same as in the PPA. http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-304.43-driver.html Sorry for assuming Ubuntu, Linux Mint (not Debian edition) is based on Ubuntu. Compiz itself actually **recommends** using nouveau: http://smspillaz.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/beware-the-benchmarks/