# GNOME 3.8 on a dual screen setup freezes after lock screen

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, gnome

I recently installed Arch Linux, and with that GNOME 3.8.2 + GDM 3.8.1.1.

I have this on a Notebook with an Intel graphics card with the notebook LCD and an external monitor attached via VGA port. I'm using intel driver module i915.

This is the problem I'm having:

1. I lock the screen, whether through the lock button in the user menu or by pressing ctl+alt+l, the screen blanks and both monitors suspends (like suspending power).
2. When I try to resume working, moving the mouse or pressing a key, both screens resume power but the login screen is frozen.

Notes:

- When frozen, I can switch to another TTY just fine.
- This only happens when I'm using the dual screen setup, if I only use one screen (doesn't matter if I use the onboard notebook LCD or the attached VGA) everything works fine.
- By "the login screen is frozen" I mean that the screen shows an incomplete screen (like it crashed before it was able to complete rendering) with a grey area in the bottom of the screen. Also the Mouse will not work. Also note that the screen will go powersaving correctly after 20 secs, and if I move the Mouse or press a key, the screen will wake up but in the same condition.

Here is a screenshot of the screen when in the described state:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, having seen your edit, my answer is irrelevant. Could you post your `~/.xsession-errors` file? Also try updating your xorg and anything else that might be relevant. I had a [similar problem](http://superuser.com/q/466235/151431) and it went away after a large update.

Comment: I did a clean boot, logged in, locked the screen, froze as always, and **nothing** new in `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Also check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and make sure you have an up to date `xorg` package.

Comment: Nothing either on `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when the system freezes. As I said I recently installed this (last weekend) and I pretty much updated all packages daily in search of a solution for this issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you only get this with VGA screens? When I had the problem I linked to in my previous comment, DisplayPort worked fine, only VGA was screwed up.

Comment: I only tried it with VGA, but I will definitely get some DVI or HDMI cable and test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the system to (the now released) `GDM 3.8.3` and `xf86-video-intel 2.21.11` and the issue is fixed. I'm assuming there was a bug in older versions of one of those packages that affected my system.

Comment: how you do that? how to upgrade that package?

Comment: @AhmadMuzakki depending on your Linux distribution it can be done with apt-get, yum or whatever package manager you OS has.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "the login screen is frozen" but assuming your X session is alive and running, you should be able to fix it with [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr):

1. Figure out an `xrandr` line that correctly sets up your system. For example, I have a VGA screen to the right of my laptop. I get the screens' names by

   ```
   $ xrandr | grep -w connected
   VGA-0 connected 1440x900+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   DP-3 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   ```

   So, since I know my VGA screen is to the right of my laptop, I can recreate this layout with

   ```
   xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --primary --right-of DP-3 \
          --output DP-3 --mode 1600x900
   ```
2. [Map](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.5/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) the `xrand` command to a keyboard shortcut of your choice and use it to reactivate your screens.

If all is not well with your X session, you can do the same thing by dropping to a tty and running

```
export DISPLAY=0:0
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --primary --right-of DP-3 \
           --output DP-3 --mode 1600x900
```

Comment: Thanks @terdon. Unfortunately the `xrandr` command didn't help; I can't access my X session, and from a TTY I get the error: "Can't open display" (or "Can't open display 0:0").